# Loading Image to cache which is stored in the xml file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have application in which i am loading xml file into the cache by giving url i have following code for it:

```
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    cachedResponse = [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:response data:responseData userInfo:nil storagePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] storeCachedResponse:cachedResponse forRequest:request];
```

After this i am parsing the xml file getting from the web.In xml file there is url for image and video when i am loading that image from the url it just taking long time for it. Can I load those images at the time of parsing by using cache? Or is there any other way to avoid loading of images at the time of displaying ?

Comment: You can parse XML, and then you find Url for image and video. And you want load that image and video without making user see blank image or the placeholder you might be using. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by 2 ways:

1. Load image and video in fore ground before making UI (where you want to display your image), I believe that is a worst idea as it'll stuck your UI while image and video content will be loading.
2. Load image and video in background thread and while loading show an dark layered spinner over the screen. Don't forget to remove spinner as soon as your downloading finished.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few libraries out there to help you do this type of thing. One popular one is [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). It has a cache built in and it downloads images asynchronously.

Here is an example of SDWebImage in action:

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                        success:^(UIImage *image) {... success code here ...}
                        failure:^(NSError *error) {... failure code here ...}];
];
```